# GroupBy items and count item every hour in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset with a 'datetime' object as index

```
index                                Item

2016-10-30 09:58:11                 Bread
2016-10-30 10:05:34          Scandinavian
2016-10-30 10:05:34          Scandinavian
2016-10-30 10:07:57         Hot chocolate
2016-10-30 10:07:57                   Jam
2016-10-30 10:07:57               Cookies
2016-10-30 10:19:12                Pastry
2016-10-30 10:19:12                Coffee
2016-10-30 10:19:12                   Tea
2016-10-30 10:20:51                Pastry
2016-10-30 10:20:51                 Bread
2016-10-30 10:21:59                 Bread
2016-10-30 10:21:59                Muffin
```

Being new to Pandas I am a bit lost on how to groupby the dataframe. I need the two things 1) item count for every hour, like total count for 'Bread' every hour

Something like the following

```
index           item          count

 2016-10-30 09:00:00   Bread   3
 2016-10-30 10:00:00  Coffee  10
 2016-10-30 11:00:00   Toast   1
```

Then a total count of items in the 24-hour day span

```
index          item  count

 2016-10-30    Bread  13
 2016-10-30   Coffee  1200
 2016-10-30    Toast  19
```

Probably two separate operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) and aggregate by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

dates = df.rename_axis('Dates').index.floor('H')
df1 = df.groupby([dates,'Item']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
                Dates           Item  count
0 2016-10-30 09:00:00          Bread      1
1 2016-10-30 10:00:00          Bread      2
2 2016-10-30 10:00:00         Coffee      1
3 2016-10-30 10:00:00        Cookies      1
4 2016-10-30 10:00:00  Hot chocolate      1
5 2016-10-30 10:00:00            Jam      1
6 2016-10-30 10:00:00         Muffin      1
7 2016-10-30 10:00:00         Pastry      2
8 2016-10-30 10:00:00   Scandinavian      2
9 2016-10-30 10:00:00            Tea      1
```

---

```
dates = df.rename_axis('Dates').index.floor('24H')
df2 = df.groupby([dates,'Item']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
       Dates           Item  count
0 2016-10-30          Bread      3
1 2016-10-30         Coffee      1
2 2016-10-30        Cookies      1
3 2016-10-30  Hot chocolate      1
4 2016-10-30            Jam      1
5 2016-10-30         Muffin      1
6 2016-10-30         Pastry      2
7 2016-10-30   Scandinavian      2
8 2016-10-30            Tea      1
```

If `Series`:

```
print (type(s))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

dates = s.rename_axis('Dates').index.floor('24H')
df2 = s.groupby([dates,s]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: Edited the question, note the index is of datetime object

Comment: @Wajih - ya, my solution working only with `DatetimeIndex`.

Comment: Am trying it out. Give me couple of minutes

Comment: Super! Thanks for the solution. Works awesome!